# Como obter neste código a url da categoria [Magento]?

Tags: php, magento

Este código me retorna as categorias do Magento mas não consegui fazer ele incrementar a url da categoria para que seja clicável e vá para a página da categoria correspondente. Podem me ajudar?

```
    <ul>
        <?php
            $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
            $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
            Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : $currentCategoryId='';
            foreach ($storeCategories as $_category):
        ?>

        <li>
            <strong>
                <?php echo "<a href=".$_category->getUrl().">" . $_category->getName(); "</a>"; ?>
            </strong>
        </li>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `$obj->getStoreCategories()` pega informações básicas da categoria que não inclui a url, o ideal então é ter a referencia direta ou um novo objeto, eu prefiro a referencia direta como código abaixo:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        $obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
        $storeCategories = $obj->getStoreCategories();
        Mage::registry('current_category') ? $currentCategoryId = Mage::registry('current_category')->getId() : $currentCategoryId='';
        foreach ($storeCategories as $_category):
            $url = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId())->getUrl();
            // altere a variavel no echo  abaixou ou defina o valor
            // $_category->setUrl($url);
    ?>    
    <li>
        <strong>
            <?php echo "<a href=".$_category->getUrl().">" . $_category->getName(); "</a>"; ?>
        </strong>
    </li>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```